# BetterBibtex/Biber/Zotero - No export of Book Pages

Tags: biber, zotero, better-bibtex

I'm using Zotero (V.5.0.81) and BetterBibtex (V.5.2.7) in order to export my bibliography to a .bib file. When I do that, my `pagetotal` field for @books doesn't appear in my .bib.

It works well on another computer, therefore I don't understand why `Nb of pages` Zotero field isn't automatically exported.

EDIT :

I want to have the `pagetotal` field in my .bib after my exportation. Therefore, the total number of pages for @books. On my another computer my Zotero field `Nb of pages` is automaticaly converted in a .bib `Pagestotal`. It is not the case now.

There, an example of the same Zotero `@book` reference converted on my two computers in a `.bib`. The only difference between my two configurations is the version of BetterBibtex (V.5.1.58 and V.5.2.7) :

Old .bib :

```
@book{bueltzingsloewenHecatombeFousFamine2007,
  langid = {french},
  location = {{Paris}},
  title = {L'h\'ecatombe des fous: la famine dans les h\^opitaux psychiatriques fran{\c c}ais sous l'Occupation},
  shorttitle = {L'h\'ecatombe des fous},
  pagetotal = {512},
  publisher = {{Aubier}},
  date = {2007},
  keywords = {History,France,Psychiatric hospitals,20th century,Atrocities,German occupation; 1940-1945,Killing of the mentally ill,Victims of famine,World War; 1939-1945,ag},
  author = {von Bueltzingsloewen, Isabelle}

}
```

Now :

```
@book{bueltzingsloewenHecatombeFousFamine2007,
  title = {{L'h{\'e}catombe des fous: la famine dans les h{\^o}pitaux psychiatriques fran{\c c}ais sous l'Occupation}},
  shorttitle = {{L'h{\'e}catombe des fous}},
  author = {von Bueltzingsloewen, Isabelle},
  year = {2007},
  publisher = {{Aubier}},
  address = {{Paris}},
  groups = {Approche g{\'e}n{\'e}rale,Asiles},
  keywords = {20th century,ag,Atrocities,France,German occupation; 1940-1945,History,Killing of the mentally ill,Psychiatric hospitals,Victims of famine,World War; 1939-1945},
  language = {fr},
  lccn = {RC450.F7 B84 2007},
  timestamp = {2019-06-09T11:32:56Z}
}
```

Thank you for your help.

ANSWER :

The problem was that I was exporting with BetterBibtex which doesn't support `pagestotal` field. Exporting with BetterBibLatex solves the problem.

Comment: by pages do you mean number of pages? Zotero doesn't have a pages field for books.

Comment: While `biblatex`'s standard data model accepts a `pages` field for `@book` entries it isn't used all that much. `pages` usually refers to the range of pages that the work takes up in a larger work (for example the page range of an `@article` in its journal, or of an `@incollection` chapter), for `@book`s that usually doesn't apply. If one wants to refer to a specific page (range) of a book that is usually done in the citation. Do you really need a `pages` field here? ...

Comment: ...  I would have mentioned that [Better BibTeX](https://retorque.re/zotero-better-bibtex/) lets you configure the `.bib` file export of your Zotero database quite extensively, but if Zotero simply doesn't have a `pages` field equivalent for `@book`s, then that might not be an option. As adam.smith hints at, there is a field for the total number of pages in `biblatex`: `pagetotal` (not sure about Zotero support for that field).

Comment: Thank you for your Help. By pages, I Mean the total number of pages, the `.bib` `pagetotal` field. Usually, on my last computer the Zotero field `Nb of pages` of @books was automaticaly converted to `pagetotal` field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you export as biblatex rather than bibtex, the pagetotal field will show up.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But my problem is that I want the total number of pages of @books ( `Nb of pages` field in Zotero converted in `Pagetotal` field in biblatex). Sorry for the misunderstanding, I edited my question.

Comment: I've edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you again, it works well !  But it's strange I'm pretty sure that Zotero has a field for book entries : `# of pages` as you can see in this documentation : [Zotero doc](https://www.zotero.org/support/kb/item_types_and_fields). And this field was converted with my last version of BBT. Sorry to bother you and thank you again.

Comment: You are correct. If you open an issue on the BBT GH page, I'll add it.

Comment: I'll do it, thank you very much.